# Find out running on XP embedded

Tags: language-agnostic, windows-xp, embedded

Is there a way to find out if my program is running on XP embedded? I've tried .NET System.Environment.OSVersion, but the version information looks like that of a "normal" Windows XP, except for the minor version number, and relying on that seems to fragile to me.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? In general it seems more appropriate to test for the particular things you need. XP embedded can be configured, and the difference between configurations may be the same order of magnitude as the difference with "normal" XP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A Microsoft eMVP (Bing Chen) on Egg Head Cafe suggests [GetVersionEx and a particular version registry key](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/conversation.aspx?messageid=32537418&threadid=32537405)...

> 1. Call API
>
> ```
> BOOL GetVersionEx(LPOSVERSIONINFO lpVersionInfo);
> ```
>
> `OSVERSIONINFOEX` structure (which is
>   the output of this call)
>
> One of the members is `wSuiteMask` (a
>   WORD variable).
>
> Check the `VER_SUITE_EMBEDDEDNT`
>   (0x00000040) flag in this variable.
>
> 2. Query value in Registry
>
> ```
>  [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Product-Options]
> Key Name:   ProductSuite Type:
>
> MULTI_SZ Value:        EmbeddedNT
> ```
>
> (In XP Pro, it seems that no
>   content in this key)

While Helen Elcock suggests [looking for the FBA registry value](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/conversation.aspx?messageid=32885300&threadid=32537405):

> I check for for the DWORD registery value
>
> `[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\FBA]`
>
> You only get first boot assistant on embedded.

GetVersionEx seems like the more stable approach, because someone *might* remove the FBA key in an effort to save another couple bytes, but I'm not sure if removing that key would cause the FBA to run again anyway.  You'll probably be fine with either approach.

Comment: Don't look for the FBA key - it's not going to be there for the Win7-based Windows Embedded (Quebec).  Use the `VER_SUITE_EMBEDDEDNT` flag from `GetVersionEx()` - that's what `GetVersionEx()` is for.