# What does Environment.OSVersion return for Windows XPe(mbedded)?

Tags: c#, operating-system, environment

This question is more of a verification of assumptions than anything else. I am using the following method in creating an installer:

```
public string GetOSVersion()
{
  switch (Environment.OSVersion.Platform) {
    case PlatformID.Win32S:
      return "Win 3.1";
    case PlatformID.Win32Windows:
      switch (Environment.OSVersion.Version.Minor) {
        case 0:
          return "Win95";
        case 10:
          return "Win98";
        case 90:
          return "WinME";
      }
      break;
    case PlatformID.Win32NT:
      switch (Environment.OSVersion.Version.Major) {
        case 3:
          return "NT 3.51";
        case 4:
          return "NT 4.0";
        case 5:
          switch (Environment.OSVersion.Version.Minor) {
            case 0:
              return "Win2000";
            case 1:
              return "WinXP";
            case 2:
              return "Win2003";
          }
          break;
        case 6:
          switch(Environment.OSVersion.Version.Minor) {
            case 0:
              return "Vista/Win2008Server";
            case 1:
              return "Win7/Win2008Server R2";
            case 2:
              return "Win8/Win10/Win2012Server";
            case 3:
              return "Win8.1/Win2012Server R2";
          }
          break;
        }
      break;
    case PlatformID.WinCE:
      return "Win CE";
  }
return "Unknown";
}
```

My assumption is that since XPe is basically XP Pro that it will return "WinXP" from the preceding method. I don't have access to a version to test myself, yet I know that the application will be installed on a version of XPe.

Am I mistaken?

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1399047/21336) suggests you also need to query a registry value.

Comment: devio, the question that lead to that answer you linked indicated that the minor number returned  by Environment.OSVersion.Version.Minor would be different. If that is the case I'd be satisfied with knowing that minor number.